# System.Windows.Forms reference in Resources.resx

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, project-reference

I have a class library project (.NET Framework 4.5.1) that compiles and works. When analyzing with ReSharper, it reported that the generated Resources.resx file references System.Windows.Forms, which isn't referenced in the project.

```
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="MyResource" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>...</value>
  </data>
```

- Why do I need Forms to embed a resource?
- Is there any issue with not referencing Forms? (Again, the calling code works.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Forms to embed a resource. Although the compiler uses the `System.Resources.ResXFileRef` that is located in `System.Windows.Forms` to embed your file into the dll. Just disable the warning.

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is true for Windows where an embedding of `System.Windows.Forms` is not needed, I am currently in the process of porting an C# application to Linux (using SDL2, Monokickstart etc.) and under Linux I encounter a dll-not-found error that seems to origin in the reference to `System.Windows.Forms` within the resx file.

Comment: You might consider asking a separate question (tagging it with mono, etc.) and linking to this one. That would allow people to answer your question specifically and would probably get more attention.